# html file loads in alert window (php)

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I am trying to send the user to the login page upon their submission of their registration data on the registration page. For some reason when the register button is pressed, the login page loads in an alert window (with html markup). Please have a look at the following php code. Thank You.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.digitalmoon.ca/stage_in.html');//this is the login page
//header("Location: {$_POST["stage_in.html"]}");
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'digita86_Hyperius';
$dbpass = '5xtc55xtc!';
$db = 'digita86_hero_database';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$password= ($_POST['password1']);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO hero_database_table(password) VALUE ('$password')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo 'New passcode created successfully.';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I have also tried a hidden input within the registration form in my html file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="stage_in.html" id="stage_in_redirect" 
value="http://www.digitalmoon.ca/stage_in.html"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: place your header function on the last line of your script .. and do not use echo .. it will error you .. modify header something like that

Comment: @Demonyowh Yes, that is correct. However I called it something slightly different. Just trying to make progress in the development stage. I'm new to coding so getting to this point has been a challenge. At least this file populates mySQL database correctly. I just can't seem to send people to the login page.

Comment: does `header('Location: http://www.digitalmoon.ca/stage_in.html');` ? dont work ?

Comment: ok i think i see what you're getting to .. you're trying to redirect to the login page using that hidden value in your register page right ?

Comment: @Demonyowh Ok, but I've read several times that headers must be placed before any output is sent by the script. I have read stack overflow posts that have said to put headers at the beginning because of this. I will try the script without echo. Maybe that is the problem. cheers

Answer (score 0):

first .. your form should look like this ..

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif);
h2{
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
}
hr{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
div.container{
width: 960px;
height: 610px;
margin: 100px auto;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
position:relative;
}
div.main{
width: 320px;
float: center;
padding: 10px 55px 40px;
background-color: rgba(187, 255, 184, 0.65);
border: 15px solid white;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
border-radius: 2px;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
input[type=text] {
width: 97.7%;
height: 34px;
padding-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-top: 8px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00F5FF;
border: 2px solid #00F5FF;
color: #4f4f4f;
font-size: 16px;
}
label{
color: #464646;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}
#register {
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 15px;
background: linear-gradient(#22abe9 5%, #36caf0 100%);
border: 1px solid #0F799E;
padding: 7px 35px;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #13506D;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100%;
}
#register:hover{
background: linear-gradient(#36caf0 5%, #22abe9 100%);
}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="post" action="http://www.digitalmoon.ca/do_register.php">
  <h2>Generator Prime Registration</h2>
  <center><label>Please enter a personal passcode that will be used when staging in. Thank You.</label></center>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Please store your passcode." />
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" id="redirect_to" value="http://www.digitalmoon.ca/stage_in.html" />
  <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />

</form>
```

then you should have do_register.php that will have the code:

```
<?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'digita86_Hyperius';
    $dbpass = '5xtc55xtc!';
    $db = 'digita86_hero_database';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $password= ($_POST['password1']);
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hero_database_table(password) VALUE ('$password')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header('Location: ' . $_POST['redirect_to']);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I believe I need to output the user's password they submitted with the form to the database. How else can I do that?

Comment: Isn't this the same as what OP did?

Comment: you can execute queries or anything , just dont echo .. echo displays output and that what leads you to error ..

Comment: never mind the input hidden @Swellar .. i just restructured it in a much readable way .. my answer is putting the header at the end of the script and do not output anything before the function ..

Comment: cool. but I got rid of the echo and the issue persists. please have a look at the registration page at [link] http://digitalmoon.ca/generator_prime_registration.html thanks

Comment: I tried to implement the first answer but now there is no action on the pressing of the register button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start();
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'digita86_Hyperius';
$dbpass = '5xtc55xtc!';
$db = 'digita86_hero_database';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser,      $dbpass);
$password= ($_POST['password1']);
mysql_select_db($conn, $db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO hero_database_table(password) VALUE   ('$password')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo 'New passcode created successfully.';
mysqli_close($conn);
ob_end_flush();
header('Location: http://www.digitalmoon.ca/stage_in.html');//this is the login page
}
?>
```